# Reverse DNS on AzureVM

Tags: azure, internal-dns, reverse-dns

I've created a VM that holds the private and public DNS zones for my network. I'm having difficulties setting up a pointer record for my domain name that's being used for exchange.

My best guess is that only the ISP can setup the PTR record in this case Azure. Does anyone have any tips or advice as to how this setup should be done?

Comment: Yes, only the owner of the network can set up a PTR record for the network. You should contact Azure support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [New-​Azure​Rm​Public​Ip​Address](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/new-azurermpublicipaddress?view=azurermps-4.0.0) to  create a public IP address with a reverse FQDN.

```
$publicIp = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $publicIpName -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
        -AllocationMethod Static -DomainNameLabel $dnsPrefix -Location $location -ReverseFqdn 
    $customFqdn
```

I find a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092478/reverse-dns-with-static-ip-while-using-azure-resource-manager) about configure Reverse DNS on Azure VM step by step. You could check it.

Comment: Good Morning Walter, Thank you for this reply. I've had to re-create my VM and reconfigure AD, will implement this tonight hopefully that will solve the problem. Once I've tested it i'll accept here.

Comment: @AlexP OK, if you have any issue, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response, reading your answer I was able to find the following page that explains how to update an existing IP's reverse DNS.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-reverse-dns-for-azure-services

Thanks again.